# How to check array visit may out of bounds using sonarqube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, indexoutofboundsexception, sonarqube-scan

How to check array may out of bounds using sonarqube ? There is nothing about this in existing rules. Custom rule ?

I want to find array visit without index check.

Noncompliant Code Example

```
String[] spiltResults = chatString.split(ch);
result = spiltResults[0];
```

Compliant Solution

```
String[] spiltResults = chatString.split(ch);
if(spiltResults.length > 0){
    result = spiltResults[0];
}
```

Comment: an array won't go out of bounds. it's the invalid indices programmers allow to be used that go out of bounds. what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Stultuske I've edited the question.

Comment: I'm not sure a rule like that exists. But I'm pretty sure you can add your own rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a custom rule in SonarCube that requires there to be an explicit bounds check prior to any array subscripting operation.

However, there are a few problems:

1. It is relatively easy to test that there is always an explicit check.
2. It is harder to test that the check is correct.
3. It is very hard to test that the correct action is taken when the index expression would be out of bounds.
4. It is very hard to deal with code where the programmer has left out a check that is unnecessary, has hoisted the check out of a loop, or similar.

Here's the rub.  If you can implement a custom rule that does 1) and 2) but not 3) and 4) then the net result will be that you are encouraging programmers to write ugly code with redundant checks to make SonarCube "just shut up".   That is a bad thing, and probably *worse* for real code quality than not implementing the rule at all.

A better approach is to test thoroughly.  You should be doing this anyway.  (Relying on a code analyser to find your bugs is a bad idea.)

Indeed, you could argue that it is better for the code throw index check exceptions when there are bugs, than to encourage the programmer to add sloppy range checking code that may actually make the real bugs harder to find.

---

FWIW, SonarCube most likely doesn't have a standard rule for this.  Such a rule would produce too many false positives to be useful for real-world code bases.

Comment: nice post , very useful ：)